# Unable to access admin web page

Tags: admin

When I try and access the web-admin page I get a message;

Your server is running PHP version 5.5.38 but WordPress 5.2.1 requires at least 5.6.20.

I recently upgraded PHP to version 7.3.  I have checked the cPanel and indeed it says I am running 7.3 for this site.  I am not sure what to try next.

Comment: Try to change the php version from 7.3 to 5.6 it will solve your problem.

Comment: You should speak to your host. If WordPress isn't running on PHP 7.3 then whatever you changed in cPanel isn't working, but cPanel doesn't have anything to do with WordPress itself.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by following the instructions here;

http://www.beyondmyfrontdoor.com/wp/how-to-fix-wordpress-reporting-the-wrong-php-version/

I turned out that the .htaccess file was loading an old version of php as follows;

```
# Use PHP55
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php55/lib
</IfModule>
```

I commented this out and it now allows me access to the admin web page again.